# How to set "Deliver on" using parse.com android?

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

On website there is the field "Deliver on", it's like Delay Sending.

But how to set it to push notification when create it in the Android app?

I found that

```
long weekInterval = 60*60*24*7; // 1 week
push.setExpirationTimeInterval(weekInterval);
```

it is Expiration Time...But I want to set time of delivery
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sending scheduled push notifications is not currently supported by the Parse Android SDK.

But you can do that by using the [REST API](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/REST) or the [JavaScript SDK](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/JavaScript) (or do that manually from the web console check out the [section 7](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notificationshttp://)). In order to do so, you have to have the [Parse Cloud](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) setup. So you can make use of the JavaScript SDK or REST API from their Parse Cloud.